# python - While Loop causes entire program to crash in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to run a While Loop in order to constantly do something. At the moment, all it does is crash my program.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
def a():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
    while True:
        print("test")

a()
```

It will loop the `print` statement, however the actual canvas refuses to open.

**Are there any viable infinite loops that can work alongside Tkinter?**

**Extra Information**
When I remove the `While True` statement, the canvas reappears again.

Comment: I haven't actually used `Tkinter`, but from the documentation it looks like you must call the `pack` method to actually display an object (such as a canvas).

Comment: Hi there Kyle. Thanks for the comment. Basically when I remove the "While True" and just have it print text, the canvas does appear. I will edit that extra information into my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tkinter hangs unless it can execute its own infinite loop, `root.mainloop`. Normally, you can't run your own infinite loop parallel to Tkinter's. There are some alternative strategies, however:

## Use `after`

[`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) is a Tkinter method which causes the target function to be run after a certain amount of time. You can cause a function to be called repeatedly by making itself invoke `after` on itself.

```
import tkinter

#this gets called every 10 ms
def periodically_called():
    print("test")
    root.after(10, periodically_called)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.after(10, periodically_called)
root.mainloop()
```

There is also [`root.after_idle`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_idle-method), which executes the target function as soon as the system has no more events to process. This may be preferable if you need to loop faster than once per millisecond.

## Use `threading`

The [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module allows you to run two pieces of Python code in parallel. With this method, you can make any two infinite loops run at the same time.

```
import tkinter
import threading

def test_loop():
    while True:
        print("test")

thread = threading.Thread(target=test_loop)
#make test_loop terminate when the user exits the window
thread.daemon = True 
thread.start()

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

But take caution: invoking Tkinter methods from any thread other than the main one may cause a crash or lead to unusual behavior.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Your solution works well, but I also want to implement it in some other programs too. Is there a way that involves looping WITHOUT a function?