# Threading In Tkinter To Stop Mainloop From Freezing

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter

I'm creating a Shoot 'Em Up game in Tkinter using the canvas. The user controls a sprite that is continually shooting bullets in the direction it is facing along the x axis.

I have run into a problem whilst trying to animate the bullet moving across the screen. I'm using a `while True` loop to keep the bullet moving continuously, however this causes the program to freeze.

From my research I understand that I may have to use threading to stop the maintop from freezing up, however I have not been able to find any easy to follow guides on threading in Tkinter online.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Canvas
import time

window1 = Tk()
window1.title("Shoot 'Em Up")
window1.config(background="black")
window1.geometry("600x300")


def move_spryte1_up(event):
    xspeed = 0
    yspeed = -10
    canvas.move(spryte1, xspeed, yspeed)
    Tk.update(window1)


def move_spryte1_down(event):
    xspeed = 0
    yspeed = 10
    canvas.move(spryte1, xspeed, yspeed)
    Tk.update(window1)


def move_spryte1_left(event):
    xspeed = -10
    yspeed = 0
    canvas.move(spryte1, xspeed, yspeed)
    Tk.update(window1)


def move_spryte1_right(event):
    xspeed = 10
    yspeed = 0
    canvas.move(spryte1, xspeed, yspeed)
    Tk.update(window1)


def bullets():
    spryte1_pos = canvas.bbox(spryte1)
    newpos1 = spryte1_pos[1]
    newpos2 = spryte1_pos[2]-30
    newpos3 = spryte1_pos[3]-20
    spryte2 = canvas.create_rectangle(newpos1, newpos2, newpos3, newpos3, fill="blue")
    print(spryte1_pos)
    print(newpos1)
    print(newpos2)
    print(newpos3)
    while True:
        canvas.move(spryte2, 10, 0)
        Tk.update(window1)
        time.sleep(0.1)


canvas = Canvas(window1, width=600, height=300, bg="black", bd=0, highlightthickness=1, relief="ridge", highlightbackground="black")
canvas.pack()
points = [20, 40, 35, 40, 35, 30, 50, 40, 65, 40, 80, 52.5, 65, 65, 50, 65, 35, 75, 35, 65, 20, 65, 30, 62, 20, 59, 30, 56, 20, 53, 30, 50, 20, 47, 30, 44]
spryte1 = canvas.create_polygon(points, outline='red', fill='gray')
bullets()
canvas.tag_raise(spryte1)
window1.bind('<Up>', move_spryte1_up)
window1.bind('<Down>', move_spryte1_down)
window1.bind('<Left>', move_spryte1_left)
window1.bind('<Right>', move_spryte1_right)

window1.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: This question is slightly different to [python - While Loop causes entire program to crash in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731997/python-while-loop-causes-entire-program-to-crash-in-tkinter)
 as it was a question that came up when I was initially looking for help with threading in tkinter. However, I attempted the solution presented but found that it did not solve my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - While Loop causes entire program to crash in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731997/python-while-loop-causes-entire-program-to-crash-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need threads and you don't need a while loop for something this simple.

You already have an infinite loop running -- the event loop (eg: `mainloop`). You can put work on the event queue to be executed in the future with the `after` method. To perform an animation, just call a function to draw one frame, and have that function add itself back to the event queue to draw the next frame.

Here's a simple modification of your code to illustrate the point:

```
def bullets():
    spryte1_pos = canvas.bbox(spryte1)
    newpos1 = spryte1_pos[1]
    newpos2 = spryte1_pos[2]-30
    newpos3 = spryte1_pos[3]-20
    spryte2 = canvas.create_rectangle(newpos1, newpos2, newpos3, newpos3, fill="blue")
    shoot(spryte2, 10, 0)

def shoot(spryte, x, y):
    canvas.move(spryte, x, y)
    x0,y0,x1,y1 = canvas.bbox(spryte)
    if x0 < 600
        # call again in 100ms, unless the bullet is off the screen
        canvas.after(100, shoot, spryte, x, y)
```

The canvas can probably handle several dozen sprytes being moved like this before it bogs down.

BTW, you can also remove all of the calls to `Tk.update(window1)` in your move functions -- it adds overhead and slows the program down. As a general rule of thumb you should almost *never* call `update`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Bryan, using your example, how would I then make spryte1 indefinitely fire spryte2s?

Comment: @SHatna: there is conceptually no difference between moving an existing item in a loop and creating a new one in a loop. Understand the technique, and then you can apply it to all sorts of problems.