# tkinter freezing - how to use threads/.after()

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, freeze

I'm trying to create a screen time alarm app using tkinter and the time module. I used a while loop to check if the current time equals the alarm that was set by the user. If the current time equals the alarm, a Toplevel window is supposed to pop up. But my program freezes while executing the while loop.

I think I need to use a thread or .after() to fix the code but I don't understand how to use either of them.

P.S. I have already gone through similar questions and solutions on stackoverflow but I'm still confused.

```
def set_alarm():     #set the alarm by collecting values from the spinboxes

    hour = spin_hour.get()
    mins = spin_min.get()
    sec = spin_sec.get()
    while True:
        current = strftime("%H:%M:%S",localtime())
        current.split(":")
        if int(current[0]) == hour and int(current[1]) == mins and int(current[2]) == sec:
            ring() #rings an alarm & calls a function to show Toplevel window
            break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - While Loop causes entire program to crash in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731997/python-while-loop-causes-entire-program-to-crash-in-tkinter)

Comment: Take a look at [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis The OP says he has gone through a lot more of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to continually check the time. You can use after to schedule the alarm at the given time. Just compute the number of seconds between now and the date in the future.

For example, if the alarm is set for exactly one minute from now, that's 60 seconds or 60,000 milliseconds. To ring the bell in 60,000 milliseconds you would call `after` like this (assuming `root` was the reference to the root window):

```
root.after(60000, ring)
```