# While loop makes the tkinter GUI doesn't appear when i use this loop in it. What can i use instead?

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, pyautogui

While loop makes the tkinter GUI doesn't appear when i use this loop in it. What can i use instead? My code so far:

```py
while 1:
         if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
                pyautogui.typewrite(f'{spam.get()}')
                pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - While Loop causes entire program to crash in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731997/python-while-loop-causes-entire-program-to-crash-in-tkinter)

Comment: it doesn't. I need it to loop because otherwise when i press enter nothing  happens.

Comment: It ideally should, but I wrote an answer for you which is the same thing but for your use case. I do recommend you to go through it though

Answer (score 1):

The infinite `while` loop freezes the main thread and so the GUI doesn't respond, try using `.after(interval,function)`. Example,

```py
def is_pressed_enter():
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        pyautogui.typewrite(f'{spam.get()}')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
    root.after(100,is_pressed_enter)
```

This will loop your function every `100` milliseconds to do the check.

If you truly need an infinite `while` loop, then you might want to look into `threading`.